# splash video full screen issue android

Tags: android

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    VideoView videoHolder;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,           
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        try{
            videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
            setContentView(videoHolder);
            Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                    + R.raw.splash);
            videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);

            videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    jump();
                }

            });
            videoHolder.start();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            jump();
        }
    }


    private void jump() {
        if(isFinishing())
            return;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

I am not able to view the splash video in full screen tried a lot...but it is only in the upper half portion ......what changes should I do to make the video in full screen its not working for me please suggest

Comment: Set theme for Splash Activity  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in your manifest file.

Comment: i did but video remain in the upper half but earlier the lower part was white now it became black but video remain in the upper half

Comment: set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` also for splash Activity in manifest file.

Comment: its showing ..........error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|screenSize').

Comment: Just check that u have set it in proper place

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity

Comment: Then there will be no any issue

Comment: its showing error...Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|screenSize').

Comment: when i am seeing in the vertical mode in phone then its showing in upper half but when i am seeing in tilted rectangle mode then its shoeing in full mode .....how to make full view in vertical mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `layout`(which you create in layout folder) using `setContentView` method in *onCreate* if you want to add only `VideoView` using `setContentView` then set a layout-parameter as `MATCH_PARENT` for both *height* and *width* for that videoview.

If you want to use the layout do something like this

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
try{
       Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                  + R.raw.splash);
       videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);

       videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

       public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            jump();
       }

   });
   videoHolder.start();
} catch(Exception ex) {
     jump();
}
```

Comment: finally ...thnx a lot kaushik :)

Answer (score 0):

onCreate Method changes :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,           
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

try{
    videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
    setContentView(videoHolder);

    VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.splash);
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);

    videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            jump();
        }

    });
    videoHolder.start();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    jump();
   }
}
```

This might be solve your problem.

Comment: please notify clearly where to make changes or please paste the exact code

Comment: video is still in half mode not in full screen

Comment: please add xml file in question.

Comment: added please see to it